# Restriction on the parameters entered for the attribute in an Object in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to store permissions given to a user in an object format in my MongoDB using Mongoose. The Object format for the permissions should be as follows

```
"permissions":{
       "EventManagement": "ADMIN",
       "SportManagement": "READ"
}
```

My requirement is that I must check whether the object attribute(i.e. `EventManagement`,`SportManagement`) values is either `READ`, `WRITE` or `ADMIN`. In my model, `permissions` is of type `Mixed`. When I added `ENUM` restriction on the `permissions` and posted the data with object Attributes(i.e `EventManagement`, `SportManagement`) values other than `READ`, `WRITE` and `ADMIN` got stored in my MongoDB Database.

My model for permissions is as follows

```
 permissions: {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        required: true,
        enum:["READ","WRITE","ADMIN"]
    }
```

Can somebody suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: why did you use type `Mixed` instead of `String`?

Comment: As mentioned in [Mongoose API Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), MIXED is datatype which take data in whatever format we give with not limit. Since my requirement is that the permissions be dynamic, hence I gave it as MIXED and not as String.

Comment: `enum` can only be used with defined `String` fields, not `Mixed`.

Comment: Hi Johnny can you suggest an alternative ?

Comment: @shubhamagiwal See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565682/how-to-restrict-values-using-mixed-data-type-in-mongoose) also asked today.