# How to restrict values using Mixed data type in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using [mongoose.js](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) with [node.js](https://nodejs.org/). I have a mongoose schema as shown below.

```
myModel: {
     type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
}
```

I want to restrict the values in the schema to predefined values of type 
`String` where as my keys should be dynamic.

For example,

```
 myModel: {
     "Dynamic Key 1" : "Restricted value 1",
     "Dynamic Key 2" : "Restricted value 2",
     "Dynamic Key 3" : "Restricted value 3"
 }
```

where my values must accept `Restricted value 1`, `Restricted value 2` and `Restricted value 3` only allowing keys to accept anything without any restrictions.

Is [Schema.Types.Mixed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) the right type to be used here? If not, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to avoid dynamic keys if possible as they make everything harder. Instead of using `Mixed`, give the field more structure by making `myModel` an array that contains a dynamic `key` *value* and a string `value` field that's validated using `enum`:

```
myModel: [{
    key: String,
    value: {
        type: String, 
        enum: ['Restricted value 1', 'Restricted value 2', 'Restricted value 3']
    }
}]
```

Your example doc would become:

```
myModel: [
    { key: "Dynamic Key 1", value: "Restricted value 1" },
    { key: "Dynamic Key 2", value: "Restricted value 2" },
    { key: "Dynamic Key 3", value: "Restricted value 3" }
]
```